# wordpress visual composer video player not working on mobile

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, youtube

I am adding a YouTube video to a wordpress site using the 'visual composer' video player from WPBakery. I cant really post the site because its private. But I am new to 'Visual Composer'.

I added the relevant you tube video to a 2 column 'row' on the right using the VC video player. It all works fine on desktop, but as soon as you narrow the browser so its in 'responsive' mode like the width of a mobile/tablet lets say 700px the you tube video stops working...

You can see the YouTube background image but you cant rollover with the mouse to start/activate the video, almost as though the video itself is not present and only the holding image.

Does anyone know how to configure settings so you can activate the video on mobile/tablet as well? As far as I can see I have not tabbed 'hide on any device' so any help would be welcome. It maybe that its a fault with the theme but as I am new to VC am hoping there is some setting that will solve the issue.

Answer (score 8):

You can re-enable the video by adding the following css to the page:

```
.vc_video-bg.vc_hidden-xs {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: This works to a degree but doesn't the video no longer play automatically.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this @RobertSheppard

Answer (score 0):

I finally found one solution that worked for me and I hope this might work for someone else as well, so here I go:

I used Revolution Slider and created a separated slider for each "div" element I wanted to have with a background video in fullscreen.

Then I added one video layer, choosed the source type and inserted ID of video.

I basically followed this explanation on this website: https://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/video-layers/

I hope this helps future users as it helped me. :)